# Calculating service area for trucking drive time of 11 hrs around point using ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, service-area

[image]

I see the maximum cut of limit for generating a service area is 5hrs or 300 min from [ArcGIS documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/itemdesc-generate-service-areas.htm). This is the cut off duration.

If I try to provide beyond that, there is an error popping up.

```
Error : 030122: Exceeding largest break value
Error : 030024: Solve returned failure.
```

Is there any alternative to obtain the service area?

[image]

Comment: What tool(s) with all parameter values are you using?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Sample Screenshot of Locally installed Network Data set]

Raised this issue with ESRI Support and got a solution from Technical Support Analyst who works on Network Analysis. Going into the details.

The issue can be solved using Local Network Dataset instead of the network data set that uses ArcGIS Online. While using the Business Analyst for ArcGIS we get a Network Data set which is installed locally. This solves the issue.